# deriving regular expressions from a regular language

Tags: regex, regular-language

Given the language below, how do i find a regular expression for the language

L = {a ^n b ^m | n => 1, m =>1, nm =>3}

Comment: Can you provide a link to a description of the notation you're using? I think I know what most of it means, but I'm not sure what 'nm' means.

Comment: @sepp2k  Not in the Set description I think. What would nm =>3 mean then?

Comment: @Martin: Bah, of course you're right. I didn't read properly. Guess it just means multiplication then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

n>=1 and m>=1 and nm>=3 is true for each of the following:

n=1,m>=3

n>=3,m=1

n>=2,m>=2

So L = { abbb, abbbb, abbbbb, ... } U { aaab, aaaab, aaaaab, ... } U { a^n b^m | n>=2,m>=2 }

This regex should be equivalent to L:

((abbb(b*)) | (aaa(a*)b) | (aa(a*)bb(b*)))

There is probably a much more succinct answer than this.

Comment: What does the notation "n => 1, m =>1, nm =>3" mean. Even having seen your answer I can't figure it out?

Comment: Oh and kayn if this answered your question you should mark it as answered!

Comment: It means for integers n and m, n >= 1 AND m >= 1 AND n*m >= 3. 

In set builder notation, {a ^ n | n >= 0 } = { <empty>, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ... }

Comment: @Sean the >= symbols are reversed though... looks like an arrow, if that could make any sense.

Comment: @Sean, i get your solution but am not sure why we have to include the last part where n>=2,m>=2

Comment: @NoMeN Yes I reversed them, >=,=>, same meaning.

Comment: @kayn: since it is n=>1 and m=>1 and nm=>3  we need that last part. n=2,m=2 and n=3,m=30 and so on are all valid.

Comment: @kayn:  We need to include "aabb".  The answer could be (aa*bbbb* | aaaa*bb* | aabb)

Comment: Re: succinctness: I think the most readable (for a completely subjective definition of "readable", of course) formulation is probably the one I hinted at at the end of my answer. However, I won't write that down just yet. You know, teach a man to fish and all that stuff.

Comment: I would also like to give a regular expression for the language over ∑ = {a,b,c}  so that any string in the language have at least one occurrence of each symbol.How would i represent this?

Answer (score 3):

Write down a set of example words of the language. Get a feel for them. Look for patterns. Look for common prefixes / suffixes / substrings.

```
abbb
abbbb
abbbbb
aabb
aabbb
aabbbb
aaab
aaabb
aaabbb
aaaab
aaaabb
aaaabbb
```

For example: notice that all words start with `a` and end with `b`. So, your regular expression looks something like `a...b`. What does the `...` part look like?

```
bb
bbb
bbbb
ab
abb
abbb
aa
aab
aabb
aaa
aaab
aaabb
```

This kinda looks like either an `a` followed by either at least one `a` or a `b` possibly followed by zero or more `b`s. Or simply a series of more than two `b`s.

```
a(a+|b)b*|b{2,}
```

You could also say it is either a series of at least two `a`s or a series of at least two `b`s or a series of `a`s followed by `b`s. I'm not going to write down that expression.

This *is* homework, after all, so I'll leave it to you to desugar this and put it together with the first result. (BTW: all the shortcuts I used *are* just syntactic sugar and they *do not* make regular expressions more powerful. I.e. there is a simple syntactic transformation that turns them into standard regular expression.)

[I just hope I'm right and don't make an ass of myself :-)]